# How to get a reference to the old element that was clicked so a reverse animation can be run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have 3 divs inside a container div (`"screenshots-container"`), that show imgs. I click an img in a div (`"individual-screenshot"`), it animates the `img`.

- **I can not get it to reverse the animation on the first img, when I
  click on an img in another div.**

**What I have working so far:**

If I click on the `img`, it updates its container class name from `"individual-screenshot"` to `"individual-screenshot current-screenshot"`. It then animates the img size and position.

If I click on another `img`, in another `div`, the previous `div`'s class name reverts back to `"individual-screenshot"`, and the newly clicked `div`'s class name updates to `"individual-screenshot current-screenshot"` and the newly clicked `img` animates size and position accordingly - the originally clicked `div`'s `img` does not revert back to its original position and size.

**Having problems with:**

The `img` in the `div` that was clicked in the first place does not animate back to its original position.

**HTML**

```
<div class="screenshots-container">
    <div class="individual-screenshot current-screenshot">
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/test-icon.png" style="display: inline-block; height: 200px; width: 200px; margin-left: 280px; position: relative;"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="individual-screenshot">
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/party.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="individual-screenshot">
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/test-icon.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CoffeeScript (with jQuery):**

```
showScreenShot: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $imgClicked = $(e.currentTarget)
    console.log "$imgClicked:", $imgClicked
    $div =  $($imgClicked[0].parentElement.parentNode) # img's parent div (individual-screenshot)

    $screenshotsContainer = $(".screenshots-container")
    $screenshotsList = $screenshotsContainer[0].childNodes

    $otherScreenshots = $($screenshotsContainer[0].childNodes).not($div)
    console.log "$otherScreenshots: ", $otherScreenshots

    # Adds "current-screenshot" as class for all in array
    $.each $screenshotsList, (index, value) ->
        # changes class name of div
        $value = $(value).removeClass("current-screenshot") # remove current-screenshot class name on other divs

    if $div.hasClass("current-screenshot")
        console.log "$div: ", $div
        $screenshot = $($div[0].childNodes[0].children)                                
        $screenshot.animate
            "height": "200px"
            "width": "200px"
            "marginLeft": "280px"
        .css
            "position": "relative"

    else
        # not sure how to proceed. How can I get a reference to the originally clicked div, so that I can reverse its animation back to where it was?
```

Comment: If you used CSS transitions then you wouldn't need to worry about anything other than assigning or removing classes ;)

Answer (score 0):

**A hackety hackish way so far:**

Animating the div (paddingLeft and css position) instead of the img it contains now. Still far from perfect especially because I can't cleanly reference the previously selected element.

```
showScreenShot: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $imgClicked = $(e.currentTarget)
    console.log "$imgClicked:", $imgClicked
    $div =  $($imgClicked[0].parentElement.parentNode)


    $screenshotsContainer = $(".screenshots-container")
    $screenshotsList = $screenshotsContainer[0].childNodes

    $otherScreenshots = $($screenshotsContainer[0].childNodes).not($div)
    console.log "$otherScreenshots: ", $otherScreenshots

    # Removes "current-screenshot" as class for all in array
    $.each $screenshotsList, (index, value) ->
        # changes class name of div
        $value = $(value).removeClass("current-screenshot")


    $div.toggleClass("current-screenshot")
    if $div.hasClass("current-screenshot")
        console.log "$div: ", $div
        $div.animate
            "height": "200px"
            "width": "200px"
            "paddingLeft": "280px"
        .css
            "position": "absolute"
            "top": "0"

        $.each $otherScreenshots, (index, value) ->
            $(value).animate
                "height": "100px"
                "width": "100px"
                "paddingLeft": "0"
                "marginTop": "25px"
            .css
                "position" : "relative"
                "marginTop":" 5px"
```